# get version of python module.pyd

Tags: python, windows

I load a .pyd file as python module.
Under windows I see a version when I do a right click->Properties->"Details"-Tab

How can I read (in python) the fileversion of this pyd-file?

Exists a function or something in python to read this version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`win32api.GetFileVersionInfo`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/pywin32/win32api__GetFileVersionInfo_meth.html):

```
>>> import win32api
>>> path = r'c:\python27\lib\site-packages\win32\win32api.pyd'
>>> info = win32api.GetFileVersionInfo(path, '\\')
>>> '{}.{}.{}.{}'.format(
...     win32api.HIWORD(info['FileVersionMS']),
...     win32api.LOWORD(info['FileVersionMS']),
...     win32api.HIWORD(info['FileVersionLS']),
...     win32api.LOWORD(info['FileVersionLS']))
'2.7.218.0'
```